# References does not appear using org mode and latex [SOLVED]

Tags: org-mode, latex

I am totally new using Emacs. I want to generate a Pdf file using Org mode with LaTeX. I know how to use LaTeX but I dont know how to handle my situation in Org mode.

The problem is that the references do not appear after the compilation. They only have `[?]`, and the list of references does not appear. I tried to install `org-ref` but wasn't successful, so I deiced to use the "default" package from Org and LaTeX.

> org latex insert citation ?????????????????

I try `C-c C-x [` and the minibuffer prompts for a keyword. Then I write `Oliveira2017` (the keyword from my `refs.bib` file), and the program inserts `\cite{Oliveira2017}`.. Then I compile the code with `C-c C-e l o`, and the pdf appears. But the citations have only `[?]`, and no references are printed.

This is my Org file.

```
#+latex_class: koma-article
#+latex_class_options: [captions=tableheading,a4paper, 11pt]

#+latex_header: \usepackage{graphicx}
#+lateX_header: \usepackage{natbib}

#+latex_header: \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
#+latex_header: \hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor=bblue}

#+bibliography: /home/User/Projects/LatexDocuments/refs

#+title: test
#+author: Some authors
* First chapter
Testing the citations \cite{Oliveira2017}.

\bibliography{refs.bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

My  refs.bib file is

```
@article{Oliveira2017,
abstract = {This work describes the development of a sustainable and low-cost sandwich composite structure made from aluminium skins and bonded to a tubular core with epoxy resin.},
annote = {DONE.},
author = {Oliveira, Pablo Resende and Bonaccorsi, Aline Maria Silva and Panzera, T{\'{u}}lio Hallak and Christoforo, Andr{\'{e}} Luis and Scarpa, Fabrizio},
doi = {10.1016/J.TWS.2017.08.013},
file = {:home/alberto/Downloads/a99339b8852ec079008ff92abd755a9f.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0263-8231},
journal = {Thin-Walled Structures},
keywords = {Analysis of variance,Bottle caps waste,Sandwich composites,Tubular honeycomb},
month = {nov},
pages = {38--45},
publisher = {Elsevier},
title = {{Sustainable sandwich composite structures made from aluminium sheets and disposed bottle caps}},
volume = {120},
year = {2017}
}
```

I got the bib file from Mendeley, also I am using linux. In my `myInit.org` file I set these things for latex:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
    (require 'ox-latex)
    (unless (boundp 'org-latex-classes)
      (setq org-latex-classes nil))
    (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
         '("koma-article"
           "\\documentclass{scrartcl}"
           ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
           ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
           ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
           ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
           ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
  #+end_src
```

This last code I got from the Org manual.

**Edit:** i added the next code

```
  #+begin_src emacs-lisp
;;    (require 'ox-bibtex)
    (setq org-latex-pdf-process (list "latexmk -f -pdf %f")
  #+end_src
```

The code compiles without problems but still no references only `[?]`. Then, i uncommented the `(require 'ox-bibtex)` and the next error comes up `File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, ox-bibtex`.

Comment: You probably need to add a run of `bibtex` to  your `org-pdf-latex-process` pipeline (or better yet, use `latexmk` if you can). Please edit your question and add the value of the variable `org-latex-pdf-process` which you can see with `C-h v org-latex-pdf-process`.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for your answer look, i used the next command `(setq org-latex-pdf-process (list "latexmk -f -pdf %f")`  in the `init.el` and the code compiles without errors, then i compiled the org file and the problem persists (there are not references). Also i wrote `(require 'ox-bibtex)` and the next error appears `File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, ox-bibtex`

Comment: Look at the `.tex` file that was produced: see if there are any obvious faults. Then try to process it using the same command *from the command line*: bypass what Org is doing. If that command produces the correct ref, then you should be OK from the LaTeX point of view. BTW, there is is a closing paren missing from the `setq` above: it may be a typo in the comment but you should check. And you don't need `ox-bibtex` (not for this in any case). TL;DR: just try to get the produced `.tex` file to compile and resolve the reference. That should get you there.

Comment: Also, look for the `.bbl` file that `bibtex` should have produced: does it exist? Does it look correct?

Comment: FWIW, I tried to export your Org mode file and got errors: I had to delete the two lines that deal with `hyperref` because they conflict with the `hyperref` setup that the Org mode LaTeX exporter itself does. I also deleted the `graphicx` line because it duplicates (but does not conflict) with what the exporter does; and the `#+bibliography` line because it is a no-op, so useless. With that however, I get the Org mode file successfully exported and compiled to PDF (with the  `org-latex-pdf-process` setting above) and the PDF shows the reference properly resolved.

Comment: @NickD Thank you for your answer, i did what you mentioned before and now everything works, i think that my real problem came from counsel package (some how the package created some errors that in turn affected the compilation). Also i removed the packages you already mentioned. now everything works.

Comment: Just as question, look when i compiled the `.tex` file from my terminal i used `pdflatex name.tex` and the next warning appears `LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.`. Then i run again the code and the warning is gone, but the next info appears `No file OrgLatex.bbl.`. I know that such file i can create it using `bibtex name.tex`, and then run again the `pdflatex name.tex` and everything goes quite nice. However, before i used Sublime text, and i just compiled my program with one single command and everything ran quite nice.

Comment: However, how can i just run one single command in my linux terminal to run the `name.tex` file generated by the Org file? without `Rerun` and `bibtex name.tex`. This question might more related to latex forum, but i was wondering if do you have any ideas. by the way i know that i can generate one `script.sh` and place in the script the commands needed, but i don't want that.

Comment: Since you have `latexmk`, try `latexmk -f -pdf name.tex` and see how far it gets you. However, it's good to know the individual commands: sometimes things break, and being able to run each command of the pipeline separately is a great help when debugging problems.

Comment: @NickD thank you very much my problem is already solved. Also about the individual commands, yes knowing them is really helpful. Thank you

Comment: You should add the solution as an answer to the question, and accept that solution. That causes the question to show up as solved automatically.